# Python list elements in

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask controller action with the following input validation routine, is there a way to write it more succinctly?

```
if 'firstName' and \
    'lastName' and \
    'age' \
not in request.json:
    return flask.abort(400)
```

Perhaps something like this, although I'm not sure how to get the *and* operators to work:

```
mandatory_fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'age']
if mandatory_fields not in request.json:
        return flask.abort(400)
```

Is the second code snippet possible?

Comment: Hi, can you provide me with an example of your request.json print out...

Comment: Your original example doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: Is `request.json` a string, or is it some other kind of object? I feel that this may have been closed inappropriately.

Comment: It was a dictionary, I think I understand what you mean if the boolean logic above works in a similar fashion to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `all()` method like this:

```
fields = ["a", "b", "c"]
a_hash = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}
if all(field in a_hash for field in fields):
    print("All good")
# prints "All good"

fields = ["a", "b", "c", "e"]
a_hash = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}
if any(field not in a_hash for field in fields):
    print("All bad")
# prints "All bad"
```

Comment: Thank you, I added a not e.g. if not all(...) and it worked a treat!